# Missing Keyword Error oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
witness.dob 
BETWEEN extract (year from witness.dob) '1985' AND 
BETWEEN sysdate
```

I am getting the ORA-00905: missing keyword error when trying to run my query, I belive it's this line that is causing it. Anyone know if i am doing it right or how it should be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is:

```
extract(year from witness.dob) BETWEEN 1985 AND extract(year from sysdate)
```

Here are some comments:

- Don't wrap integer constants in single quotes.
- Don't mix types in the `between` statement (say, using `1985` and `sysdate`).
- Use the correct syntax for `between`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the word BETWEEN twice

```
witness.dob BETWEEN extract (year from witness.dob) '1985' AND  sysdate
```

Answer (score 0):

`between <x> and <y>`
where `<x>` and `<y>` are values

((This is correct syntax for between) - even with extract you must keep it)